# How do I initialize the OpenSSL BIO object?

Tags: c++, openssl

I have a tcp server which detects an incoming SSL connection (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367192/how-can-i-determine-whether-an-incoming-connection-is-expecting-ssl)) and then does the following:

```
BIO* initialize(SSL_CTX *context, int socket){
    BIO *bio = NULL;
    SSL *ssl = SSL_new(context);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, socket);
    if (SSL_accept(ssl) == -1){
        return NULL; //error
    }
    //what do I do here??
    bio = BIO_new_ssl(context, 1); //this seems wrong...
    return bio;
}
```

I dont know how to create the BIO object and the documentation is really confusing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I challenge someone to find documentation more confusing than OpenSSL's.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Someone once told me that documentation is like sex: when its good, its great; but when its bad, it still better than nothing. I told them to go read the OpenSSL documentation...

Comment: Oh, come on. It takes a few hours to implement an asynchronous network I/O using OpenSSL, even if you have never used it before. Though I would not use BIO at all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excerpt of an old student project of mine (circa 2006).
I hope it sheds some light on the question. 
I do not use BIO_new_ssl() but SSL_set_bio().

```
SSL_CTX *ctx = setup_server_ctx("root.pem", NULL);
SSL_CTX *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
if (NULL == ssl) {
   fprintf(stderr, "Error creating SSL context.\n")
   goto err;
}
BIO *acc = BIO_new_accept(port);

if (BIO_do_accept(acc) <= 0) {
   fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting connection.\n");
   goto err;
}

BIO *client = BIO_pop(acc);
SSL_set_bio(ssl, client, client);

if (0 >= SSL_accept(ssl)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting SSL connection\n");
    goto end;
}   

SSL_write(ssl, SOME_MESSAGE, strlen(SOME_MESSAGE));
char buf[BUF_SIZE + 1]= {0};
int ret = SSL_read(ssl, buf, BUF_SIZE);
if (ret <= 0) { 
   break;
}   

/* do some more stuff */

SSL_get_shutdown(ssl);
```

Comment: How did this code ever work? Don't you need to call `BIO_do_accept` twice — once to bind to the port and a second time to accept the actual connection before `BIO_pop`? With only one call to `BIO_do_accept` I don't think it can work.